# How can I Re-Enable the bitnami banner in aws lightsail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have disable the the bitnami banner in aws lightsail and now i want to "re-enable the banner" for performing some test. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the disable-banner file:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/bitnami/apps/bitnami/banner/disable-banner
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just (30 minutes ago) created a new bitnami server on Lightsail, and the folder structure has changed completely !

```
/opt/bitnami/apps
```

no longer there!
I've completely lost where the bnconfig tool is, and all my config notes that were working fine last week now are all over the place.
The answer to the OP *should* be

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/bnconfig --disable_banner 0
```

but who knows now !